hide to bar extension installation for rhel8
Was wondering how to remove top bar from rhel8. Wearched online and i've found "hide top bar" extension, but it seems like it's not possible to install extensions on rhel8, am I right?
Gnome Shell Integration is installed on google chrome, but when i visit extensions.gnome.org, a popup message is showing: "although gnome shell integration extension is running native host connector is not detected"
When i look for documentation no entries for rhel8 distribution.
Anyone faced this scenario?

Gnome Shell Extension uses Firefox+Snap by default, try installing the extension using Firefox.
If that didn't work, download the package from Gnome Extensions and install it using this:
unzip your_downloaded_extension.zip ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/

